# Get javascript created button width

Tags: javascript

I created a button using javascript and I want to set it's style according to its width
but it doesn't have a width until I add it to the page.

Is there any way to know the button width before adding it to the page?

here's my code:

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button";
btn.value = "cancel";
//btn.width --> gives 0
//btn.clientWidth --> gives 0
//btn.offsetWidth --> gives 0
//btn.style.width --> gives ""
```

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: No, the button only has width once added to the DOM, unless you give it a width, which defeats the point. Why not just add it to the DOM ?

Comment: You could always guess by the `em` which would probably be the `btn.value.length`; so the `style` could come out to be `width: btn.value.length + 'em'`

Comment: Perhaps you could add it to the DOM but use `display:none`, then determine your width? (Hmmm. Does it even have width with `display:none`?)

Comment: I want to set style properties according to the desired displayed text, and I don't want to set the style after I add it to the DOM because the user might see the style change and that's something I don't want to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach would be to append your element as `hidden` to the document, and get a desired computed size using `getBoundingClientRect()`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cuqof/1/edit?js,console)**

```
function getStyle(el, style) {
    el.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return el.getBoundingClientRect()[style]; 
}


var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button";
btn.value = "cancel";
var btnWidth = getStyle(btn, 'width'); // 64
```

also, if you pass `height` you can get i.e:
`24` as the value returned from the `getBoundingClientRect` in your `getStyle` function.

Probably you might want to get rid of the `hidden` element once you get the desired value, you get the point. Just to give you an idea.

Comment: I see that there's no other way. Thx, that really helps. I will try it.